# Why can't I save my model with tensorflow lite?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

Once the training is finished, what I need is to save and convert the model to later export it, but I get the following error:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file('models/modelo.h5')
AttributeError: type object 'TFLiteConverterV2' has no attribute 'from_keras_model_file'
```

to be honest I found a problem similar to this on the web but it doesn't suit my problem. Also who gives the answer is not very explicit.
here my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras


#dataset
mnist = keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

#class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
 # def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    # If you are using Tensorflow 1.x, replace 'accuracy' for 'acc' in the next line
  #  if(logs.get('accuracy')>0.99):
   #   print("\nReached 99.0% accuracy so cancelling training!")
    #  self.model.stop_training = True

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(x_train, 
          y_train, 
          epochs=25,)
     #     callbacks=[myCallback()])

# Evaluate the model
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)

# Save the model
model.save('models/modelo.h5')

# Convert the model.
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file('models/modelo.h5')

tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("models/converted_mnist_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Comment: Have you seen these instructions https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/convert/convert_models? It says "from_keras_model" not "from_keras_model_file". But also since you have your model you can always save it as saved_model format, load it and convert it https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model